# Issues titling an equation block

Tags: equations

Does anyone know how I can put a small title right before a line that I have created without putting a large amount of space between the small title and the line? Space is of utmost importance on this page, and I need to fit all of this information here.

Here are the packages that I am using:

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amscd} % For math formatting, commutative diagrams
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[theorems,skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black} }
```

And here is the relevant Tex code:

```
\begin{figure}[h] \centering \includegraphics[width=115mm]{Lab5Schematic(v2).png} \caption{AC Amplifier Diagram} \end{figure}

\scriptsize Derived equations \normalsize %Equation formatting \begin{center} \line(1,0){480} \end{center} \begin{align*} R_o = \frac{R_c}{\beta} ~~~~   A_v = \beta \frac{R_c}{r_\pi}  ~~~~   R_{in}
= r_\pi || R_1 || R_2  ~~~~  V_c = V_{cc} - (I_c + I_{B2})R_c  ~~~~ I_E = I_S + I_0(t) ~~~~ A_{V,J} \approx g_mR_D \end{align*}

%Other Specific Quantities \begin{center} \begin{tabular}{*5l}     \toprule \emph{Design Specifications} & \emph{} &&&  \\\midrule Specs  & Voltage Gain  &  Input Impedance & Output Impedance  & Power Output (600 ohms) \\  Values  & $\approx$ 100 & 1 M$\Omega$ & 0.44$\Omega$ & 29 mW\\\bottomrule  \hline \end{tabular} \\ \end{center}

%I put the second one as \begin{flushleft} which is why we notice a difference.

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{*5l}
     \toprule
     \emph{Cont...} & \emph{} &&&  \\\midrule
     Specs    & Power Supply Voltage  &  Frequency Response & $\beta_{1=2=3=4}$ & $\beta_{5}$                           \\
     Values  & 17 V & 250-1MHz & 171 & 142\\\bottomrule  \hline
 \end{tabular} \\
\end{center}
```

[image: This is where I would like the small title.]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: both the `figure` and `center` commands add space.  to avoid the space from `center`, instead use `{\centering ... }` (or `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` instead of the braces).  and if you really don't need the graphic to float, you could use the `caption` package and `\captionof` instead of `figure`.  then you can control the spacing yourself.  oh, and welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that tomorrow, that sounds like it could work well. I appreciate the response!

Comment: Also, try adding the instruction `\raggedbottom` to the preamble.

Comment: The \centering comment fixed my issue. Thank you, that was genius!

Comment: @barbarabeeton Seems you can write an answer here :-)

Answer (score 2):

both the `figure` and `center` commands add space. to avoid the space from
center, instead use `{\centering ... }` (or `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`
instead of the braces).

if you really don't need the graphic to float, you could use the
`caption` package and `\captionof` instead of `figure`.
then you can control the spacing yourself.